Cycle bake result has partially black
I'm new to blender so forgive me for asking questions that might be dumb.
So currently I'm trying to bake the material to a texture for games, and I just need to bake one combined texture. After baking I found out that part of my model shows completely black, at first I thought it might be lighting issue, and it did fixed part of the black issue (quite strange actually). But still there're quite a lot of places that remains black.
I've checked normals, overlapping uv (I actually just use the smart uv), mesh overlapping, metallic value, these problem either not exist or has been fixed (as far as I can inspect), but the problem remains.
The blend file: 

 um is this how it works? anyway here's the file link, i think

The reason you have the unwanted black areas on parts of the baked image texture is because you have a copy of the gun and cartridges hidden in the viewport but not hidden when rendering, thus causing unwanted shadows. You will find these objects in the Outliner panel > Armature > with the names Cylinder, Cylinder.001 and SSG. To hide these items when rendering uncheck the little camera icons. See image below.


oh, my, god, I completely forgot the prototype model that stayed at the same place! thanks for pointing this out!
